# AngularJS update scope value in Promise

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

So I have this code

```
  init: ->
    @loadRootQuestion()

  methods:

    loadRootQuestion: () ->
      @$http.get(api_replies_path()).then(
        (response) =>
          @$.question = response.data.replies[0]
          @loadAnswers()
      )

    loadAnswers: () ->
      @$http.get(api_replies_path(), params: {parent_id: @$.question.id}).then(
        (response) =>
          @$.answers = response.data.replies
     )

     next: (answerId) ->
       @$http.get(api_replies_path(), params: {parent_id: answerId}).then(
         (response) ->
           @$.question = response.data.replies[0] // I get value I need here
     )
     console.log(@$.question) // can't get it here
```

The problem is scope variable can't be update outside this promise in next method, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

```
.modal-header
  button.close type='button' ng-click='close()' data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
    span
      | &times;
  h3.modal-title
    | {{ question.content }}
  .modal-body
    select name="answerSelect" ng-model="answer"
      option ng-repeat='answer in answers' value="{{ answer.id }}"
        | {{ answer.content }}
  .modal-footer
     button.btn.btn-primary.pull-left ng-if="showPreviousButton" ng-click="previous(question)" Prev
     button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right ng-if="showNextButton" ng-click="next(answer)" Next
```

It has nothing to do with view, question value just doesn't want to update in controller

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will fire immediately:

```
   console.log(@$.question)
```

Because it is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

You need to be within the callback in order to write out the data from the promise:

```
 next: (answerId) ->
   @$http.get(api_replies_path(), params: {parent_id: answerId}).then(
     (response) ->
       @$.question = response.data.replies[0] // I get value I need here

       console.log(@$.question) // you CAN get it here!
 )
 console.log(@$.question) // can't get it here
```

If you need to attach to that value, you may want to use an *Observable*.

You can also declare your variable up top to make it accessible to the entire class:

```
init: ->
    @loadRootQuestion()
    @answerValue // assign to this value

  methods:

    loadRootQuestion: () ->
      @$http.get(api_replies_path()).then(
        (response) =>
          @$.question = response.data.replies[0]
          @loadAnswers()
      )
```

Comment: `console.log` was just to explain my problem, it's not updated in the view. All I need is override that variable, but outside http call it has no effect

Comment: sorry, but where do you need to update @$.question? IN the view? Can you please show me that code?

Answer (score -1):

Inside a promise @$.question has its own scope and it is not available outside the promise.

you can declare a variable outside the http call and update the value inside the promise and assign it to @$.question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately that didn't work. Seems like http has its own scope and it's performed last that's why it can't update value I guess.